# How pass variable from jquery to php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i want way  to pass variable from jquery to php 
how to do it? ihave this code

```
<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function(){
        var title = $(this).attr('value');
        $('.div').attr('value', title);    
        });
      }); 
</script>
```

i want to pass the title of an element  to php via a javascript variable.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please be sure to read the [faq]. As a general note, please spend a little more time authoring your questions/answers to make sure they're tidy and readable.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$.ajax()` to pass the value to PHP:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('a').click(function(){
         var title = $(this).attr('value');
         $('.div').attr('value', title);
         //Communicate with file.php pass it the title via POST
         //If the php returns a true or a json value, alert it.
         //Otherwise if php returns false or an http error code, alert there was an error.
         $.ajax({
            url: "/path/to/file.php",
            data: { "title": title },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(d){
                alert("The Call was a success: "" + d);
            },
            error: function(d){
                alert("There was an error, it was: " + d);
            }
         });
         //Make sure you do this, otherwise the link will actually click through.
         return false;
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: +1 for providing full example, although I don't recommend using using fully qualified domain names (in the ajax url) in your javascript.

Comment: indeed, it was an example, you should use relational URLs... e.g. `/file.php`. Edited my answer

Answer (score 3):

you may do it with AJAX or set it into `<input name="var_name" type="hidden" value="">` field value, and after submiting get that value

Comment: +1 for including option of putting value into input box.

Answer (score 1):

You get it there with AJAX!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

With jquery you can make a call to your php page.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

The wikipedia article offers an overview of the technology and the jquery documentation provides very good complete examples.

It allows you to take data and send it to PHP from your website.

Answer (score 1):

Send AJAX request. You can pass data through `POST` or `GET`.

For jQuery:

[$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)